# ElasticSearch : search more like this in java

Tags: java, elasticsearch

Let's say I've indexed a document like this :

```
{
    "_index": "indexapm",
    "_type": "membres",
    "_id": "3708",
    "_score": 1,
    "_source": {
          "firstname": "John",
          "lastname": "GUERET-TALON"
     }
}
```

I want to retrieve this document when searching for "GUER", "GUERET", "TAL" for example.

I have a Java application and I tried this :

```
MoreLikeThisQueryBuilder qb = QueryBuilders.moreLikeThisQuery(
            "firstname^3", 
            "lastname^3")
            .likeText("GUER");

SearchResponse response = client.prepareSearch("myindex")
            .setTypes("mytype")
            .setSearchType(SearchType.DFS_QUERY_AND_FETCH)
            .setQuery(qb)             // Query
            .setFrom(0)
            .setSize(limit)
            .setExplain(true)
            .execute()
            .actionGet();
```

But this search doen't retrieve my document. Of course if I try an exact match query and search for "GUERET", it works.

Does anyone know what kind of query I have to use and how to make it work with the Java library? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The More Like This Query isn't the best choice in this case.

If, as you described, you're looking for documents using the first letters of words, you should use a Prefix Query instead, but they are limited to one field. For a search on more than one field, use the MultiMatch Query (providing the `PHRASE_PREFIX` type). I would try something like:

```
QueryBuilders.multiMatchQuery("GUER", "firstname", "lastname")
    .type(MatchQueryBuilder.Type.PHRASE_PREFIX);
```

Comment: Just tried it but doesn't seem to give any result. And what if I want to get results from "UERET", as it's not at the beginning of the word?

Answer (score 0):

```
QueryBuilders.boolQuery().should(QueryBuilders.wildcardQuery("lastname", "*GUER*"));
```

I got the result using WildcardQueryBuilder it generates following:

```
{"bool":{"should":[{"wildcard":{"firstname":"*GUER*"}}]}}
```